# Stop video automatically when certain time is set typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to limit video play within range of number that user specified.

User specified a start frame and an end frame like this.

```
frameInputEnd: 300
frameInputStart: 50
```

i recalculate those input into seconds like this

```
this.startDuration = (((1000 / this.fpsCount) * this.rangeFrame.frameInputStart) / 1000).toFixed(2);
this.endDuration = ((1000 / this.fpsCount) * this.rangeFrame.frameInputEnd) / 1000;
```

and set the `currentTime = this.startDuration`. That way user can have duration start on the frame which they have specified. I want to add an event where the video has reach the `currentTime` that is equal to `frameInputEnd` here's what i did

```
this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.ontimeupdate = (e: any) => {
  this.whatFps = `${Math.ceil(e.target.currentTime * this.fpsCount)} / ${this.totalFrame}`;
  if(this.videoPlayer.nativeElement.currentTime.toFixed(2) == Number(this.endDuration).toFixed(2)){
    this.pause()
  }
}
```

i add `.toFixed(2)` since the `frameInputEnd` is equal to 12.50 seconds. but the `currentTime` never match to 12.50 seconds, either it's 12.51 or 12.52 the video never stopped automatically.

Does anyone knows a batter way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `>=` instead of `==`

Comment: haha why i'm not aware of this, that is good, but it's stop at frame 301 not 300. do u know why?